# Networking OSX BSD Book Commands

Tags: linux, mac-osx, networking, bsd

I am looking for a good source (book, online) of networking on mac osx or linux.
What commands, how to connect, send data, security (checking for intruders) etc..
Setup server.

Thanks for the time..

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest both of these:

```
Unix in a Nutshell, Fourth Edition
By Arnold Robbins
```

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100292

```
Essential System Administration, Third Edition
Tools and Techniques for Linux and Unix Administration
By Æleen Frisch
```

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003432

They are great books to use both as references and to get a general understand of what tools are available to do what.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Absolute FreeBSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271514). It's well written in a pretty accessible style. Though I doubt you'll need to read it cover to cover, again the writing style would make it enjoyable. With a mix of history, commands, walk-throughs and tutorials it is appropriate for a beginner with enough to grow into over time. I've had it since this past summer and regret not getting it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=bsd%20networking&x=0&y=0) is an Amazon search for "bsd networking". Pick the highest-rated one from that list and get cracking.